# Detecting if click is not some specific divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I am developing a sort of horizontal menu but visible on click and hide on click but visible when click is on some arrow while hide when click is on document but not some div container. In that div container there are also some other elements.  If we write `document.onclick=closingfunction` then it close whether user click in that div itself. I want to call `closefunction` when user click anywhere but not in that div itself or on arrow.

It seems that there will be its solutions, but I haven't found one, so that's why posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery is() function to detect if current target matches specific selector:

```
$('ul.container li').click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('.dropdown')) {
        //do something when clicked inside dropdown
    }
})
```

Comment: I suppose so, but it's preferably to be more specific if it's possible to minimize number of useless events' fires.

Answer (score 1):

using Prototype you can do something like this

```
    document.observe('click', function(ev) {
        var el = Event.element(ev);
        if ((el !== $('thediv'))
                && !el.descendantOf(thediv)) {
            // hide div here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Haha, didn't even see the tag, read the question and saw the document.onclick=... and thought the OP was not using a framework, saw an opening ;)

Comment: no worries, it aslo gave me idea while obviously jquery was more useful to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's closest() to see if the click is inside the menu:
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$('body').click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).closest('.myMenuDiv,.myMenuArrow').length === 0){
    // Close it
  }
});
```